# Reuse cells with progressview

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using `ASIHTTPRequest` to download files. My custom `UITableViewCell` has `UIProgressView` where it shows the tracking of al downloads (one for each row). The cells I am using are custom and I override the `PrepareForReuse` method but I have observed a problem when I am making scroll in the tableview, the all progressviews in the cells are reseted for the method `PrepareforReuse`.

What can I do to make the progressViews display correctly? Thanks!!

**DownloadViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DownloadsCell";

        DownloadCell *cell = (DownloadCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[DownloadCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            cell.cellLabel.text = (NSString *)[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [cell.cellImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"curso.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            //cell.cellImageView.tag = indexPath.row;

            ASIHTTPRequest *request;

                request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *path = [[[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:login] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[download curso] ID]];
                NSError *error;
                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
                    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]){
                        NSLog(@"Create directory 5 error: %@", error);
                    }
                }else path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

                NSString *tmpPath = [[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TMP"];
                NSError *error2;
                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:tmpPath]){
                    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:tmpPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]){
                        NSLog(@"Create directory TMP error: %@", error2);
                    }
                }
                [request setDownloadDestinationPath:path];
                [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[[tmpPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]stringByAppendingString:@".download"]];
                [request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
                [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:cell.cellProgressView];
                //[request setDelegate:self];
                [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], @"name",
                                      [urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], @"url",
                                      nil]];
                [networkQueue addOperation:request];
                NSLog(@"Downloading %d...",indexPath.row);
}

[networkQueue go];

            return cell;
}
```

**DownloadCell.m**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70);

        cellImageView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 4, 58, 52)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:cellImageView];

        cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 200, 30)];
        cellLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cellLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cellLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:19.0/255.0 blue:121.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:13.0];
        cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [self.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];

        cellProgressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 40, 200, 15)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:cellProgressView];

        UIImageView * accesoryImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flechaAzul.png"]];
        self.accessoryView = accesoryImg;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) prepareForReuse
{
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70);
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    cellImageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 4, 58, 52);

    cellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70, 10, 200, 30);
    cellLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cellLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    cellLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:19.0/255.0 blue:121.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:13.0];
    cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    cellProgressView.frame = CGRectMake(70, 40, 200, 15);

    UIImageView * accesoryImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flechaAzul.png"]];
    self.accessoryView = accesoryImg;

    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: No actually an answer, but a way to avoid the trouble. The best practice is to have one business object for one index path and to let a cell handle an object so that all of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is dequeueing a cell and passing it the corresponding business object. This way the cell knows the previous and the new business objects it should handle, and can disconnect from the former and connect to the latter, as well as instantly update its subviews to reflect the state of the new object.

Comment: In your case a business object is a description of an asset and potentially an ongoing operation of its download. BTW `ASIHTTPRequest` is ancient, better use `AFNetworking`. It also looks like you start a request every time a row is scrolled in, but never cancel or reuse them. Either cancel requests when a cell is reused, or reuse the requests for assets you're already downloading. Otherwise some rapid scrolling back and forth can kill the networking, the battery and the app.

Comment: Yes... with rapid scrolling the app crashes. I have to get the download/requests code lines out of the cellForRow method. I try to use the tag property to identify the all progress bars. If it doesn´t work I will construct a progressViews array, adding a new bar when I creat a new request. Thanks For the answers Vadim and Wain!!

Comment: Never mind thanks, I've recommended you something totally different from what you said you're going to do. Progress views should belong to the cells and be reused together with the cells. And do not use tags for business logic.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn´t work well because the progress bar dont update when I reuse the business objects, it remais frozen with the last valor it had

Answer (score 0):

When you call `[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:cell.cellProgressView];` the `request` should be immediately updating the delegate with the current progress. If it waits till the progress changes before sending any update then you will see empty progress values until that happens.